# A combinatorial conjecture

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, congruences

I'm trying to prove the following conjecture.

**Conjecture.** Let $p \equiv -1\!\pmod{6}$ be a prime, and let $a,b > p$ be integers with $p \nmid ab(a+b)$. Then
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{p-3} \Biggl(\!\binom{p-1}{r+1}+(-1)^r\!\Biggr)\,a^rb^{p-3-r} \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p^2}.
$$

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Note that the “coefficient” is divisible by $p$ in all terms of the summation.

Comment: Is this an open conjecture or something you found out in your works?

Comment: @AngeloRendina: It's something I found in my works. I don't know whether it is a generally-known open question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some tidying up, your conjecture is equivalent to $$(a+b)^p \not \equiv a^p + b^p \pmod{p^2}. $$

However, $4^{59} \equiv 3^{59} + 1 \pmod{59^2}$.

Comment: Good catch! I forgot to put in a critical restriction: $a,b > p$.

Comment: Actually that doesn't matter since $(4+2 \cdot 59^2)^{59} \equiv (3 + 59^2)^{59} + (1+59^2)^{59} \pmod{59^2}$